# set textboxfor to accept 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor

I have these two textboxfor's and I need them to only allow input of 2 decimal places.
I'm assumming a jQuery or Javascript event can do this. I am just not sure how to call the textboxfor's in the Javascript.
Any help would be appreciated

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Categories[c].EstimateGroups[g].EstimateItems[i].PerUnitCost,
                 new { @disabled = "disabled", @onchange = "costUpdate(this);", @cstType = "perUnit",@id="perUnit"})

<span class="sideLabel">@Model.Categories[c].EstimateGroups[g].EstimateItems[i].PerUnitDescription</span>

if (Model.Categories[c].EstimateGroups[g].EstimateItems[i].Units != null
 && !Model.Categories[c].EstimateGroups[g].EstimateItems[i].IsBasedOnHomeSquareFootage)
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Categories[c].EstimateGroups[g].EstimateItems[i].Units,
                     new { @disabled = "disabled", @onchange = "costUpdate(this);", @cstType = "units" })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [RegularExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) attribute. This will do the job.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$", 
             ErrorMessage = "It cannot have more than one decimal point value")]
public double PerUnitCost {get;set;}
```

Here In `{0,2}`, 0 and 2 means minimum and maximum digits after decimal place. So change according to you requirement.

Comment: +1 very simple way. Although the query description was complex.

Comment: @PKKG, I will try to explain better next time

Comment: Sorry :) I meant, Query description.